# Camera feed not shown on ARCore Unity HelloAr Application exported to Native Android Application as library

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, arcore

I have run sample Unity Hello-AR on my device using guide lines from following link
https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/unity/quickstart-android
It is working fine.

**But when I export this unity project as library to native Android** using the technique given in following link
https://medium.com/@davidbeloosesky/embedded-unity-within-android-app-7061f4f473a

The camera feed does not show. Whereas rest of buttons and snackbar show up. I have checked for the Camera Permission but it is not working even if granting the permission manually.

Following is my logcat error messages shown

```
10-25 23:41:26.018 20420-20420/soft.aasharib.arcoreintegrate E/Zygote: isWhitelistProcess - Process is Whitelisted
10-25 23:41:26.019 20420-20420/soft.aasharib.arcoreintegrate E/libpersona: scanKnoxPersonas
    Couldn't open the File - /data/system/users/0/personalist.xml - No such file or directory
10-25 23:41:26.317 20420-20420/soft.aasharib.arcoreintegrate E/ViewRootImpl@470227[MainActivity]: Surface is not valid.
10-25 23:41:26.467 20420-20487/soft.aasharib.arcoreintegrate E/Unity: Google AR Error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.unity3d.unitygar.GoogleAR" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/soft.aasharib.arcoreintegrate-PUl65upN4UYH79MhLvu6Ww==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/soft.aasharib.arcoreintegrate-PUl65upN4UYH79MhLvu6Ww==/lib/arm, /data/app/soft.aasharib.arcoreintegrate-PUl65upN4UYH79MhLvu6Ww==/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]Didn't find class "com.unity3d.unitygar.GoogleAR" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/soft.aasharib.arcoreintegrate-PUl65upN4UYH79MhLvu6Ww==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/soft.aasharib.arcoreintegrate-PUl65upN4UYH79MhLvu6Ww==/lib/arm, /data/app/soft.aasharib.arcoreintegrate-PUl65upN4UYH79MhLvu6Ww==/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
10-25 23:41:26.593 20420-20487/soft.aasharib.arcoreintegrate E/Unity: Unable to find unitygar
10-25 23:41:29.182 20420-20487/soft.aasharib.arcoreintegrate E/Unity: Unable to find arcore_unity_api
10-25 23:41:29.194 20420-20487/soft.aasharib.arcoreintegrate E/Unity: Unable to find arpresto_api
10-25 23:41:29.245 20420-20487/soft.aasharib.arcoreintegrate E/Unity: DllNotFoundException: arcore_unity_api
        at (wrapper managed-to-native) GoogleARCoreInternal.ARPrestoCallbackManager/ExternApi:ArCoreUnity_setArPrestoInitialized (GoogleARCoreInternal.ARPrestoCallbackManager/EarlyUpdateCallback)
      at GoogleARCoreInternal.ARPrestoCallbackManager._Initialize () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
      at GoogleARCoreInternal.ARPrestoCallbackManager.get_Instance () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
      at GoogleARCoreInternal.ARCoreAndroidLifecycleManager.get_Instance () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
      at GoogleARCoreInternal.LifecycleManager.get_Instance () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
      at GoogleARCore.ARCoreSession.Awake () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

    (Filename:  Line: -1)
10-25 23:41:29.255 20420-20487/soft.aasharib.arcoreintegrate E/Unity: DllNotFoundException: arpresto_api
        at (wrapper managed-to-native) GoogleARCoreInternal.ARCoreAndroidLifecycleManager/ExternApi:ArPresto_setEnabled (bool)
      at GoogleARCoreInternal.ARCoreAndroidLifecycleManager.DisableSession () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
      at GoogleARCore.ARCoreSession.OnDisable () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

    (Filename:  Line: -1)
```